# Does Android Canvas is the best way to do an animation?

Tags: android, animation, canvas, android-animation

All. I implemented an animation and see that I almost achive the limit in 60fps.[image]

My code for this is:

layout :

```
FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:id="@+id/content"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

<View
    android:id="@+id/wave_view1"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:background="@drawable/wave_circle"
    android:layout_gravity="center"

    tools:alpha="0.2"
    />

<View
    android:id="@+id/wave_view2"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:background="@drawable/wave_circle"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />

<View
    android:id="@+id/wave_view3"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:background="@drawable/wave_circle"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />

<View
    android:id="@+id/wave_view4"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/wave_circle"
    />

<View
    android:id="@+id/wave_view5"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/wave_circle"
    />
```

and Fragemnt:

```
 private View mWave1;
private View mWave2;
private View mWave3;
private View mWave4;
private View mWave5;

private AnimatorSet setAnimation;



PropertyValuesHolder pvhX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_X, 10F);
PropertyValuesHolder pvhY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_Y, 10F);
PropertyValuesHolder alpha = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.ALPHA, 1F, 0.05F);

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frg_layout, container, false);
    mWave1 = view.findViewById(R.id.wave_view1);
    mWave2 = view.findViewById(R.id.wave_view2);
    mWave3 = view.findViewById(R.id.wave_view3);
    mWave4 = view.findViewById(R.id.wave_view4);
    mWave5 = view.findViewById(R.id.wave_view5);
    setupAnimatorSet();
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    setAnimation.start();
}

private void setupAnimatorSet(){
    setAnimation = new AnimatorSet();

    setAnimation.play(waveAnimation(mWave1));

    setAnimation.play(waveAnimation(mWave2)).after(1000L);

    setAnimation.play(waveAnimation(mWave3)).after(2000L);

    setAnimation.play(waveAnimation(mWave4)).after(3000L);

    setAnimation.play(waveAnimation(mWave5)).after(4000L);

}



private ObjectAnimator waveAnimation(View view){
    ObjectAnimator scaleAnimation =
            ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(view, pvhX, pvhY, alpha);
    scaleAnimation.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
    scaleAnimation.setDuration(5000L);
    return scaleAnimation;
}
```

So, my question is. To achieve the better performance Do I need to do everything on canvas?

> Update

[image]

Comment: yes, use one custom `View` instead of 5

Comment: but I need to animate size and alpha

Comment: yes, what is the problem then? use `ValueAnimator` / `ObjectAnimator` with "animation" code in `ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener`

Comment: something like [this](http://pastebin.com/jjt0gPwD)

Comment: @pskink Thank for the time. So, I took your approach and modify for circles. and you can see that performance still not really good

Comment: @pskink just change it a little http://pastebin.com/GMru5ajk

Comment: so try to use just one Animator instead of 4 and simulate 3 others, of course you have to use some math to do that